# Chatter when delegate=True in odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

I am using delegate=True and i want chatter for partner_id which i am not able to do because of delegate what should i do

```
order_id = fields.Many2one("sale.order", "Order", delegate=True, required=True, ondelete="cascade")
```